# Initialize object - using namespaces

Tags: php

I have prepared a simple php class with one constructor.
In this same file I have also initalized the class.
Everything works fine until the namespace is activated.
Below script works fine.

```
<?php


require_once('../inc/settings.inc.php');


class Auth 
{
   private $pdo;
   private  $stmt;

    
    public function __construct () 
    {
        try {          
                $this->pdo = new PDO(PCC_DRIVER . ':host=' . PCC_HOST . ';dbname=' . PCC_DB, PCC_USER, PCC_USER_PASS);
                $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
                $this->pdo->query('SET names utf8');
                $this->pdo->query('SET character_set_client = utf8');
                $this->pdo->query('SET character_set_results = utf8');
                $this->pdo->query('SET character_set_connection = utf8');
                $this->pdo->query('SET character SET utf8');
            }
            catch (Exception $ex)
            {
                echo 'Exception -> ';
                var_dump($ex->getMessage());
            }
             $this->stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM klienci");
             $this->stmt->execute();
            while ($row = $this->stmt->fetch()) 
            {
                echo $this->x=$row['name']."<br />\n";       
                
            }
    
    }
}

$auth =  new Auth();
echo $auth;
```

The record was returned.

But when including the namespaces it stopped.

```
<?php

namespace Pcc\System;
require_once('../inc/settings.inc.php');


class Auth 
{
   private $pdo;
   private  $stmt;

    
    public function __construct () 
    {
        try {          
                $this->pdo = new PDO(PCC_DRIVER . ':host=' . PCC_HOST . ';dbname=' . PCC_DB, PCC_USER, PCC_USER_PASS);
                $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
                $this->pdo->query('SET names utf8');
                $this->pdo->query('SET character_set_client = utf8');
                $this->pdo->query('SET character_set_results = utf8');
                $this->pdo->query('SET character_set_connection = utf8');
                $this->pdo->query('SET character SET utf8');
            }
            catch (Exception $ex)
            {
                echo 'Exception -> ';
                var_dump($ex->getMessage());
            }
             $this->stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM klienci");
             $this->stmt->execute();
            while ($row = $this->stmt->fetch()) 
            {
                echo $this->x=$row['name']."<br />\n";       
                
            }
    
    }
}

$auth =  new Pcc\System\Auth();
echo $auth;
```

The browser returned Error 500.
Do you know why it happens ? Is it someting wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$auth =  new Pcc\System\Auth();
```

instead try

```
new Auth();
```

only.

Also please define the classes you want to use below namespace like :

```
use PDO;
```

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Pcc\System\PDO' not found in C:\wamp64\www\devProjects\pccSources\pcc\app\libs\system\Auth.php:17
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp64\www\devProjects\pccSources\pcc\app\libs\system\Auth.php(42): Pcc\System\Auth->__construct()
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\wamp64\www\devProjects\pccSources\pcc\app\libs\system\Auth.php on line 17

Comment: Great so `use PDO;` below namespace will solve it by this your class can use PDO if you import it :)

Answer (score 1):

The Error says Class 'Pcc\System\PDO' not found.

It means it is looking for class PDO in the Pcc\System namespace (relative path). It is because you did not tell your program to look from the root (absolute path).

Try

```
$this->pdo = new \PDO(PCC_DRIVER . ':host=' . PCC_HOST . ';dbname=' . PCC_DB, PCC_USER, PCC_USER_PASS);
```

and

```
$auth =  new \Pcc\System\Auth();
```